Batch Search from Google search API
I am in a project in where the system needs to search bulk of inputs via Google and save the responses. I have tried to do the search sequentially using Google custom search API for the inputs but it takes too much time. Is there any possibility perform a batch search on Google?
PS: I am aware that Google custom search API does not support batch search.
